# Initializing class object-array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, copy-constructor, initializer

Is there a way to initialize an array like so:

```
static const vec3d<long> XI[Q] = {
     vec3d<long>( 0, 0, 0 ),

 vec3d<long>(-1, 0, 0 ),  vec3d<long>( 0,-1, 0 ),  vec3d<long>( 0, 0,-1 ),
 vec3d<long>(-1,-1, 0 ),  vec3d<long>(-1, 1, 0 ),  vec3d<long>(-1, 0,-1 ), [etc]
};
```

where

```
00039 template<typename TYPE>
00040 class vec3d : public vec<TYPE>{
00041 public:
00042 
00049         vec3d() : vec<TYPE>( 0, 3 ){};
00057         vec3d( TYPE right ) : vec<TYPE>( right, 3 ){};
00065         vec3d( TYPE X_val, TYPE Y_val, TYPE Z_val ) : vec<TYPE>( 0, 3 ){
00066                 this->val[0] = X_val;
00067                 this->val[1] = Y_val;
00068                 this->val[2] = Z_val;
00069         };
00077         vec3d( vec3d<TYPE>& right ) : vec<TYPE>( 0, 3 ){
00078                 this->val[0] = right[0];
00079                 this->val[1] = right[1];
00080                 this->val[2] = right[2];
00081         }; [etc] };
```

and

```
    00040 template<typename TYPE>
    00041 class vec{
    00042 public:
    00047         TYPE *val;
    00052         int dimension;
    00053 public:
    00060         vec();
    00066         vec( TYPE right );
    00073         vec( TYPE right, int _dimension );
    00081         vec( vec<TYPE> &right ); 
    00082 
    00087         ~vec();
    00088 
    00089 
    00090         TYPE& operator[]( int right);
    00091         vec<TYPE>& operator=( TYPE right );
    00092         vec<TYPE>& operator=( vec<TYPE> &right );
[etc] };
```

Source is:

```
00049 template<typename TYPE>
00050 vec<TYPE>::vec( TYPE right, int _dimension ){
00051         dimension = _dimension;
00052         val = new TYPE[_dimension];
00053         assert( val );
00054         for( int i = 0; i < dimension; i++ ) val[i] = right;
00055 
00056 };

00075 template<typename TYPE>
00076 TYPE& vec<TYPE>::operator[]( int right ){
00077         assert( ( right < dimension ) );
00078         assert( right >= 0 );
00079         assert( val );
00080         return val[right];
00081 };
```

are constructors. Q is declared "static const int", so it should fulfil C++ standard of being non-variable, right?

Compiler says: 
error: no matching function for call to ‘albm::vec3d::vec3d(albm::vec3d)’
vec3d.h:77:2: note: candidates are: albm::vec3d::vec3d(albm::vec3d&) [with TYPE = long int]

Obviously there is the problem, that I can't pass vec3d& here. Is there some workaround? Defining every single vector first seems to be a solution. Would be a hazzle though...

And sorry for my stupid question...maybe this thread exists somewhere, but I didn't find it. Probably this issue has some special name I don't know - therefore I can't google it!
"extended initializer list", "class array initialisation" and such didn't do the trick...

**SOLUTION:** some postprocessing here...maybe so. else encounters the same prob:
The copy constructor lacked a "const":

```
00077         vec3d( const vec3d<TYPE>& right ) : vec<TYPE>( 0, 3 ){
00078                 this->val[0] = right.val[0];
00079                 this->val[1] = right.val[1];
00080                 this->val[2] = right.val[2];
```

Further I can't access right[] directly - my guess for a reason would be the template-style - but right.val[] does the trick!

Comment: Post a *minimal* and *complete* code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your copy-constructor is not correctly declared - 
the toCopyFrom parameter needs to be **const**:

```
vec3d<TYPE>( const vec3d<TYPE>& toCopyFrom)
```

Edit:

Now, on your second problem regarding the subscript operator:

The subscript operator `operator[]()` in your base class does not have `const` (i.e. read-only) semantics.  In your copy constructor, you were trying to access values in `right` through that subscript operator.  Now, that `right` parameter is declared const, which basically means that you are not allowed to change the internal state of `right`.  Since your `operator[]()` function is not const, the language's assumption is that the function could mutate/alter the state of `right` - which conflicts with `right`'s const-ness.  Indeed, the function actually returns a reference to the internal member variables of the class, which would allow a client of that code to change the internal state of `right`!

The solution is to provide an additional, const, subscript operator in the base class:

```
const TYPE& operator[]( int right) const
```

*Note - personally, I'd rename `right` to `index` - for clarity.*

The trailing `const` on the above function signature provides it with const access semantics, which allows you to call - for instance - x = `right[n]` when `right` is `const`.  The leading const on the return type just means that the returned TYPE reference will be const, which prevents you doing `right[n] = x` when `right` is const.  Note - when you add the function, its implementation (body) of the function should probably look the same as for the existing subscript operator.  You did not provide that, so I cannot write it.

In conclusion, I would suggest you read up on const and 'const-correctness' topics.

Comment: vec3d.h:78:3: error: passing ‘const albm::vec3d<long int>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘TYPE& albm::vec<TYPE>::operator[](int) [with TYPE = long int]’ discards qualifiers

Comment: I think you may need to post a little more code, especially including the operator[]() member function.

Comment: oh and...I didn't overload it (vec::operator[]) again to vec3d::operator[] - should be covered by base class, right?

Comment: Well using this->val[0] = right.val[0]; in vec3d, line 78 does the trick - but why?

Comment: I had a similar problem with accessing val[] directly within vec3d class. Therefore I used this->val[]. Could it be the same issue with templates not allowing right[] but only right.val[] ???

Comment: See my edits as to why right[n] failed in the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
00039 template<typename TYPE>
00040 class vec3d : public vec<TYPE>{
00041 public:
00042 
00049         vec3d() : vec<TYPE>( 0, 3 ){};
00057         vec3d( TYPE right ) : vec<TYPE>( right, 3 ){};
00065         vec3d( TYPE X_val, TYPE Y_val, TYPE Z_val ) : vec<TYPE>( 0, 3 ){
00066                 this->val[0] = X_val;
00067                 this->val[1] = Y_val;
00068                 this->val[2] = Z_val;
00069         };
00077         vec3d( vec3d<TYPE>& right ) : vec<TYPE>( 0, 3 ){
00078                 this->val[0] = right[0];
00079                 this->val[1] = right[1];
00080                 this->val[2] = right[2];
00081         }; [etc] };
```

the copy constructor defined at line 77 has non-`const` argument, which cannot be bound to an rvalue argument.

Just remove lines 77 through 81.

The compiler will generate a nice copy constructor for you.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Now it's complaining about: no matching function for call to ‘albm::vec3d<long int>::vec3d(albm::vec3d<long int>)’